# How to add incremental numbers for a big list automatically?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a big list like the following

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
.
.
```

How do I make the list like following automatically with some linux utility without having to do it manually?

```
["Afghanistan",1],
["Albania",2],
["Algeria",3],
["Andorra",4],
.
.
```

Using sublime text search `^(.*)$` and replace `["\1",],` I am able to get the following

```
["Afghanistan",],
["Albania",],
["Algeria",],
["Andorra",],
.
.
```

How do I add the numbering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This awk:

```
$ awk '{ print "[\"" $0 "\","++var"]," }' file
["Afghanistan",1],
["Albania",2],
["Algeria",3],
["Andorra",4],
["Angola",5],
```

- It prepends `["` to each line.
- It appends `",` + variable + `],"` to each line.

By saying `++variable`, we make the variable value start printing at `1` and from that to the end of the file. In case you want to start from another number you can declare the value previously:

```
$ awk -v var=5 '{ print "[\"" $0 "\","++var"]," }' file
["Afghanistan",6],
["Albania",7],
["Algeria",8],
["Andorra",9],
["Angola",10],
```

Comment: Surely `NR` would suffice, rather than using a separate variable?

Comment: Well it could, true. I added some explanation to show that this would be handy if the OP wants to start from a certain number (whereas this could also be made with `NR+value`, true).

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this in awk:

```
awk '{printf "[\"%s\",%d],\n", $0, NR}' file
```

This simply processes each line of the file and wraps it in the format you need. `NR` is a special variable, which corresponds to the current record (line) number.

One thing to remember with `printf` (I forgot!) is that you have to manually append a newline `"\n"`...If portability is a concern, you can use the special variable `ORS` (Output Record Separator), which should correspond to a newline on your platform:

```
awk '{printf "[\"%s\",%d],%s", $0, NR, ORS}' file
```

If you use `print` and concatenate strings yourself (as [fedorqui has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26926746/2088135)), the Output Record Separator is automatically appended, so you don't need to worry about these things.

Answer (score 0):

Try below awk,

```
awk '{print "[\""$0"\","NR"],"}' filename
```